# SMTP email encryption

Tags: node.js, email, encryption, smtp, nodemailer

How to encrypt the email that's sent using SMTP? I am sorta new to this SMTP and got a bit confused between *email encryption* and *SMTP server authentication*.

I can't really find an example where SMTP mail is sent in an encrypted format (using tls/ssl) without any authentication.

My case is, I have an SMTP server (which does not require any authentication). I have to send the email message in an encrypted format.

So, is it really not possible to **send an email without any server authentication**? Please clear me here.

Below is my code for reference, which doesn't work when **security is set to true**.

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: prop.mailHost,
  port: prop.mailPort,
  secure: true  //encrytpion enabled. And no authentication provided               
});     

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
  if (error) {
    return console.log(error);
  }
  console.log("successfully sent mail");
}
```

Am I missing something here? [Nodemailer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer) is the node js package which is used here. I'm free to switch to some other node js package, as long as it supports mail encryption & adding attachments.

Comment: I suspect you're misunderstanding the authentication in the SSL context. The SSL/TLS client always authenticates the SSL server before sending data. The client must be configured with a list of certificate authority(CA) certificates that covers all the possible servers the client may connect to. I don't know how nodemailer does this, you'd have to check the docs. You say "it doesn't work"  but no clue as to how it fails.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to mix up several security aspects:

- **SMTP authentication** means, that the mail client is required to send user/password to authenticate itself to the server. This is a configuration in the SMTP server. If authentication is required, but not provided, the server will refuse to accept the mail. SMTP is possible without authentication, and that was in fact the default for a long time in the early days of the internet (called "open relay"), but when spammers started to abuse such servers for the delivery of their spam mails, this changed. Nowadays, probably no SMTP server accepts mail unless authenticated.
- **TLS or STARTTLS** means that mail client and SMTP server setup a secure channel over which they send the email. This is very similar to SSL. SMTP with TLS start an insecure connection, then (using the STARTTLS command) negotiate to setup a secure channel before sending data. **Secure SMTP or SMTPS** initiate an SSL connection first, then start the SMTP protocol over it. Setting *secure* to *true* in the transporter properties means that TLS is requested during SMTP. But this has nothing to do with the above.
- **Email encryption**, which you also mention, is something else. It means that the message itself is encrypted by the sending client, and decrypted by the receiving client. Unlike TLS or SSL which are only secure transport channels, email encryption is a real end-to-end encryption. Email encryption is usually performed using S/MIME or PGP. But this has nothing to do with the above.